# VSTO outlook addin - uploading huge files blocks outlook till process in finished

Tags: c#, async-await, vsto, outlook-addin, windows-forms-designer

I'm working on an Outlook addin.When composing a new email, user can select huge attachments and on ***click of send*** (ItemSend event handler), add in is uploading files to Azure cloud storage. To track the progress I'm showing the upload progress using a progress bar. I'm facing an 2 issues here. Firstly, Progress bar is grey and unresponsive. I don't see the progress at all. Secondly, ***outlook is completely blocked*** till upload is finished. But the requirement is, till the upload is in progress, user should be free to use outlook for ex. check other mails, send different mails and so on.

Calling method:

```
    ProgressForm.Show()
//**Syncronization context is not null before calling
      var result = await ProgressForm.UploadFiles(files);
// **Perform action based on result. as of now control doesn't return back here
```

For uploading the files I've async method which does below operations

```
    public async Task<bool> UploadFiles(List<UploadFilesListModel> filesList)
    {
        try
        {
            //**Synchronization context is not null here**
            Print((SynchronizationContext.Current is null) ? "sync context null" : SynchronizationContext.Current.ToString()));

            foreach (var file in filesList)
            {
                //using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob cloudBlockBlob
                var cloudBlockBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(file.Uri));
                int blockSize = 256 * 1024;              
                using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file.Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    int blockCount = (int)((float)fileSize / (float)blockSize) + 1;
                    List<string> blockIDs = new List<string>();
                    int blockNum = 0;
                    int bytesRead = 0; 
                    long bytesLeft = fileStream.Length; 

                    while (bytesLeft > 0)
                    {                           
                        blockNum++;
                        int bytesToRead;
                        if (bytesLeft >= blockSize)
                        {                               
                            bytesToRead = blockSize;
                        }
                        else
                        {                              
                            bytesToRead = (int)bytesLeft;
                        }
                        string blockId = GetBlockID(blockNum);
                        blockIDs.Add(blockId);
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[bytesToRead];
                        fileStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytesToRead);
                        string blockHash = MD5Hash(bytes);
                        //upload single block
                        await cloudBlockBlob.PutBlockAsync(blockId, new MemoryStream(bytes), blockHash);
                        bytesRead += bytesToRead;
                        bytesLeft -= bytesToRead;
                      
                        //**update progress bar here**
                        progressBar1.Invoke(updateProgress); 
                       //**also tried using progress.Report(bytesRead); where progress is IProgress<int> but does not work
                    }
                    //**upload all blocks**
                    await cloudBlockBlob.PutBlockListAsync(blockIDs);                        
                }
            }             
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Each time I upload one block  using `cloudBlockBlob.PutBlockAsync`, I update the progress bar using `IProgress<int> progress`.
But this does not work as expected, I don't see the updating progress and also outlook is blocked and I can't do any other operations in outlook.
I'm new to VSTO and async concepts, so any leads are appreciated.
Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What's `cloudBlockBlob`? What's the value of `SyncrhronizationContext.Current` there?

Comment: @PauloMorgado - cloudBlockBlob  is from Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob. Synchronization context is available in the calling method, but in the called method it is null. I added the complete code now. Hope it helps.

Comment: Where is it blocking? Can you make a smaller repro? What happens if you remove all progress reporting?

Comment: @PauloMorgado - I added logs and tried to replicate the scenario. Its blocking at await cloudBlockBlob.PutBlockAsync and it doesn't continue or come to an end. Same is the case even if I comment out progress bar upload part. One more correction, synchronization is not null in the called method, I corrected it in the question now.

Comment: Try this instead: `var result = await Task.Run(() => ProgressForm.UploadFiles(files));`

Comment: @PauloMorgado - I tried using Task.Run as you mentioned. It runs fine without progress bar update. Progress bar (tried with Invoke and also with Sych context send and push) update still doesnot work fine. Program gets stuck exactly at progress bar update and doesn't come to end. Task.Run creates a background thread and updating UI from background thread does not go fine.

Comment: Even if you use `IProgress<int>`?

Comment: @PauloMorgado - Even with  `IProgress<int> ` I don't see the progress bar updating. But it doesn't block the code at least.

Comment: From what I learnt `IProgress<int> ` internally uses `SyncrhronizationContext post` which just asynchronously triggers UI update and proceeds with the other operations. But seems outlook object model doesn't allow updating modeless forms from background thread. See here => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/threading-support-in-office?view=vs-2019 . But using just  `async ` and  `await ` instead of  `Task.Run ` does not create background thread and it should run fine in this case, which is not working but. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You want to get out of the UI thread and `Task.Run` is the better way to do it. VSTO is tricky.